# click on a div to expand it and click on it to close it using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not sure why I can't replicate this function on my website. First off, something that is mind boggling is that it works on one page. I can literally copy every piece of code off that page and when i try to build a new page in the same directory i can't replicate the same functions. **I'm looking at the "COMMISSIONS" button on the left hand menu.**

Here is the code that's on the page that functions correctly.

```
<li class="has-sub ">
    <a href="javascript:;">
        <i class="icon-table"></i> 
        <span class="title">Commissions</span>
        <span class="arrow "></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub">
       <li ><a href="freedomtextim/multi pay Life_ printable payout spreadsheet_published.xlsx">Life Grid</a></li>
       <li ><a href="freedomtextim/annuities/annuity multi pay_ printable payout spreadsheet_published.xlsx">Annuity Commission</a></li>
       <li ><a href="freedomtextim/FEG Promotional Guidelines 2014.docx">Promotional Guidelines</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

When you inspect element this is what you see:[image: has sub and arrow are the divs that change]

When you click and inspect element this is what changes after click, it changes from `display none` to `display block:` [image]

and finally the div names change to `sub open` and `arrow open`[image]

Here is my code:

```
<li class="has-sub ">
    <a href="javascript:;">
       <i class="icon-table"></i> 
       <span class="title">Commissions</span>
       <span class="arrow "></span></a>
       <ul class="sub" style="display: block; overflow: hidden: 40.234671256042006px; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 3.498667065742783; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 3.498667065742783px; ">  
           <li ><a href="freedomtextim/multi pay Life_ printable payout spreadsheet_published.xlsx">Life Grid</a></li>
           <li ><a href="freedomtextim/annuities/annuity multi pay_ printable payout spreadsheet_published.xlsx">Annuity Commission</a></li>
           <li ><a href="freedomtextim/FEG Promotional Guidelines 2014.docx">Promotional Guidelines</a></li></ul>
```

i tried to just add the additional code to get it to work.. you'll see that in the second bit of code "Here is my code". I can't figure out why if i copied and pasted everything from the original page to a new page it won't work.. all the same code is there.. frustrating..

The only javascript on the page is a couple snippets:

```
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=800,width=1200,left=0,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}

<!-- BEGIN RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
                <a class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" id="main_menu_trigger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="arrow"></span>
                </a>          
                <!-- END RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'll post it now.. i just realized i left it out.

Comment: there should be some javascript which is adding/removing the class open, where is it?

Comment: Likely there are some external scripts that are included on the original page, but not on yours. Look for `<script>` tags with URLs.

Comment: they are all completely the same.. i've copy and pasted everything over and just created a new page..

Comment: I find your lack of Javascript...disturbing.  Do you understand that you need event hooks and event handlers to change the css and hide/show elements?  I'll bet the event handlers from the working page were added to elements in JS on pageload.  This is why copying just the HTML and newPopup() function are not enough.

Comment: I'm understanding what you're saying but i do not really understand where they are running or how i could run them on my new page. Any help in the right direction is appreciated @Seano666. Thank you.

Comment: What I'm saying is the click event is being set, and Javascript is being executed to hide and show that element.  Only you have not found  and copied that code.  Is this a real website that we can look at?

Comment: It's a dashboard on a custom cms, unfortunately no.. I could post the entire code from the page.. it's really not that lengthy at all. if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery try this out:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<ul>
    <li class="has-sub">
        <a href="#" id="commbtn"><span class="title">commissions</span></a>
        <ul class="sub" id="hideShowComm">
            <li ><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li ><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul> 

<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#commbtn').live('click', function(event) {        
            jQuery('#hideShowComm').toggle('show');
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Code Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/un9B7/2/)

As long as all your pages have the same id's on the elements you want to control this should work.

Comment: @cooking-good also, I would suggest looking at those console errors you're getting in the screenshot, they might be related [ ctrl + shift + j ]